# Find and copy with xargs doesn't work in a script

Tags: scripting, find, cp, xargs

I need to find three files from a huge directory and copy them to another directory.

This is what I have done:

```
find $adir -type f \( -name "a1*" -o -name "a2*" -o -name "a3*" \) -mtime -8 | xargs cp -t $bdir
```

The file `a1` is copied to the destination but other files are not copied to the destination.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date)
day=$(date +"%u")
adir=/x/y
bdir=/a/b
 {
      if [ "$day" == "5" ] ; then
         find $adir -type f \( -name "a1*" -o -name "a2*" -o -name "a3*" \) -mtime -8 | xargs cp -t $bdir
       else
           echo "failed"
       fi
    }
```

I am running this in a script and the cursor does not return to the terminal.
Is there any way I can get it to work?

Comment: What makes you thin it's not working? If `$adir` is the root of a vast directory structure, then it _would_ take some time to look through all files. Also, you are limiting with `-mtime -8`, are you sure those files are modified within the last 8 hours? The command also does not copy only `a1` but any file than _starts_ with `a1` (etc.).

Comment: When I run it on a command line the find is  working fine.When  I use it in BASH script just one file ie,a1 is getting copied, a2 and a3 are not getting copied

Comment: Well, it's "working" insofar that it's not giving you any error messages, right? In that case, insert `set -x` on the line before the `find` in the script to see what actually gets executed. It could be that you have an unexpected value in, for example, `$adir` (this variable should be double-quoted, by the way, as should `$bdir` be).

Comment: Also, if "the cursor is not returning to the terminal" when executing the _script_, then there could be something else in the script that is wrong.

Comment: The problem is just one file "a1" is being copied others are not.

Comment: Again, do insert `set -x` before the invocation of `find` to verify that the command is executed in the way you believe it should be.

Comment: Added set -x no error, waited for 10 min still not returning to terminal.

Comment: There is no way for us to debug this issue with the information that you have provided. The script look ok (except that the variables really ought to be double-quoted, as I pointed out earlier), and even though one might have chosen to do it slightly differently, what you have there looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets. This command works for me direcly in terminal and in a bash shell (changed cp to 'file' to check it works..):

```
 find . -type f -name "a4*" -o -name "d1*" -o -name "f2*" -mtime -8 | xargs file
```

You can also try a for loop, which might give you some more space (loop) to do thigs. Change the `find` line with

```
for a_file in `find $adir -type f \( -name "a1*" -o -name "a2*" -o -name "a3*" \) -mtime -8`
do
   cp -t $a_file $bdir
done
```

You can play removing the `-mtime -8` and change `cp -t $a $bdir` for `echo "The file is: " $a_file` for testing...

Comment: This works for me too in terminal but not on script

Comment: As commented by  Kusalananda, put set -x, but after "#!/bin/bash" and try again.

Comment: @Innov Just to be absolutely clear: the `set -x` will not _fix_ anything, but will allow you to see what commands actually gets executed.

Comment: With set -x I see the command works exactly as I want it to but the files seem not to get copied

Comment: Your script (with "file" instead of "cp") is working for me. Can you change cp for file? Do you see all the output when adding 'set -x' (it is a minus, not a plus). Also, remove the '\(' and '\)' and try

Comment: Just one file "a1" is copied now  a2 and a3 are not getting copied

Comment: @ferranm sorry but "file" instead of "cp" ??

Comment: 'xargs file' instead of 'xargs cp' is just for testing. It will show a line with info about the file, so nothing is broken... You should see info about each 'finded' file. This way you can play with the shell...

Comment: I used xargs file everything looks  fine.

Comment: Also, can you see all the lines outputted by 'set -x'? Do all variable resolution match what you want?

Comment: @Innov, by fine you mean that you see something like "./filexxx.png: PNG image data, 280 x 190, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced" for each file?  (change PNG for your extension...)

Comment: They are all tar files and they look good

Comment: Ok. Please, try putting xargs this way:  xargs cp {} $bdi

Comment: Okay I did this now I am getting an error for a2-file.It says Cp: ​​The specified target is not a directory

Comment: Sorry, i meant "xargs -I {} cp {} $bdi"

Comment: Again just one file is being copied.

Comment: I have to leave, but you can have a look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/ (go to "Avoiding errors and resource hungry problems with xargs and find combo" at the end). Hope it helps...

Comment: Last tip... check permisions for files in source and destination directory... (now I'm really gone ;-)

Comment: @Innov, back again and tried again. Your script works. So problem might be with `-mtime X` filter or issues with source/destination files (permisions, free space...). Play on the terminal with the `find` comand (i.e. no mtime) without `xargs`  and check results... Good kuck !!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, your script looks syntactically and grammatically correct, so there must be something outside the script itself that causes it to behave in the way that it does.

Having said that, I can give you my own take on the script.  This is the way I would have written the equivalent thing:

```
#!/bin/sh

day=$(date +'%u')
adir='/x/y'
bdir='/a/b'

case "$day" in
    5)  find "$adir" -type f -mtime -8 -name 'a[123]*' -exec cp {} "$bdir"/ ';'
        ;;
    *)  printf 'Error: Unhandled day "%s"\n' "$day" >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

This just uses the fact that the various names that you'd like to match may be matched by a single filename globbing pattern. It also does not have a dependency on GNU `cp` and its `-t` option (got rid of `xargs`).  And since it's not using any "bashisms", it may as well be interpreted by `/bin/sh`.

The `case ... esac` is easier to read (and write) than a bunch of `if ... then ... elif`.